# How do I get all my archived Gmail into iCloud mail?

Tags: icloud, mail.app, email, gmail, mobile-mail

How do I get all my archived Gmail into iCloud mail?

I don’t just want it in the Mail client, I actually want it on iCloud servers for future reference.

For example, an email I sent using Gmail 10 years ago, should be accessible in iCloud mail on the web, iPhone and Mac apps.

Comment: Why do you want to move it? You can easily configure your mail client to access both Gmail and iCloud.

Comment: I want to have all my data with Apple and then move on from Google and have everything in iCloud instead of searching both

Comment: I think that getting mails from GMail to Apple Mail is easy part. I personally don't know a way how to keep e-mails in iCloud Mail but syncing only subset of them to Mail.

Answer (score 3):

Find a IMAP email client, like Thunderbird.
Configure both Gmail and iCloud mail as IMAP email accounts in Thunderbird.

After setup, you'll find both of you accounts in the left pane. Now you can drag and drop from Gmail to iCloud. Be patient as the process might take some time.

I haven't tested this with Thunderbird lately. You probably can use Apple Mail for this also.

A different way is to use Microsoft Outlook, configure both iCloud and Gmail. Let Gmail sync to the finish. Then you can export the mailbox and import it again into iCloud mail.

Exporting: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/export-or-backup-email-contacts-and-calendar-to-an-outlook-pst-file-14252b52-3075-4e9b-be4e-ff9ef1068f91
Importing: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-email-contacts-and-calendar-from-an-outlook-pst-file-431a8e9a-f99f-4d5f-ae48-ded54b3440ac

Comment: Won't Apple Mail do?

Comment: Thunderbird gave up after 6000 emails  so I don’t know which ones are moved and which not. I guess I can just use Gmail as an archive. Search it when I need it otherwise use iCloud.

Comment: Mmmmmm: Apple Mail might be able to do the job also. I haven't tried. You might try it :)

Comment: User32613: you might want to split the job, restart Thunderbird and try again. Eventually it will work, but it might take a bit of effort. The easy way might be using Gmail as an archive :)

Answer (score 1):

I am going through this process at the moment for the same reason: I want to migrate away from Google to Apple.

Here's what I did:

- Export all your emails from gmail in mbox format. See instructions https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10016932?hl=en
- Import box file into Apple Mail (File→Import Mailboxes). This will create a new folder in Apple Mail named something like "All mail Including Spam and Trash" (if you chose to export spam and trash)
- Select all the messages in that folder and move them to your iCloud account folder. I chose to move them all to the Archive folder.
- Wait a few days...

The last bit is really boring. I have over 80,000 messages and so far it's taken 2 days and it's still going. I estimate that at the current rate the move will take another 3 days. I have no idea why it's so slow but at least it works.